# data cleaning and formatting with awk or sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, data-cleaning

Here is an excerpt of my text file

```
 namq_aux_lp   4 Last update of data 07.07.2014  t
 namq_aux_ulc   4 Last update of data 08.07.2014  
  namq_aux_gph   4 Last update of data 07.07.2014  
  prc_hicp_cann   4 Last update of data 17.07.2014 
 namq_nace10_k   4 Last update of data 02.07.2014  clas
sei_bsco_m   4 Last update of data 10.06.2014  
ei_bsin_m_r2   4 Last update of data 26.06.2014  
 lassei_bsbu_m_r2   4 Last update of data 26.06.2014  
assei_bsrt_m_r2   4 Last update of data 26.06.2014  t
 ei_bssi_m_r2   4 Last update of data 26.06.2014  t
ei_bsse_m_r2   4 Last update of data 26.06.2014  
 ei_bsci_m_r2   4 Last update of data 26.06.2014  
10    sts_trtu_m   4 Last update of data 17.07.2014 c
```

I'm trying to format it and cleaning it, keeping it the first column and the date. However as you can see, there is the 10 on the last line. I cannot remove it because if I do, the date for `sei_bsco_m` will be amputated.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Note** Code is here https://ideone.com/JbuRHK

Desired output would be :

```
namq_aux_lp     07.07.2014
namq_aux_ulc    08.07.2014 
...
assei_bsrt_m_r2 26.06.2014
...
```

Comment: Could you also put in your desired output?

Comment: Hi Kokkie, there you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look for the first date on each line from the 7th field on and print that plus the 6th-previous field:

```
$ awk '{
    for (i=7;i<=NF;i++)
        if ($i ~ /^([[:digit:]]{2}\.){2}[[:digit:]]{4}$/) {
            printf "%-20s%10s\n", $(i-6), $i
            next
        }
}' file
namq_aux_lp         07.07.2014
namq_aux_ulc        08.07.2014
namq_aux_gph        07.07.2014
prc_hicp_cann       17.07.2014
namq_nace10_k       02.07.2014
sei_bsco_m          10.06.2014
ei_bsin_m_r2        26.06.2014
lassei_bsbu_m_r2    26.06.2014
assei_bsrt_m_r2     26.06.2014
ei_bssi_m_r2        26.06.2014
ei_bsse_m_r2        26.06.2014
ei_bsci_m_r2        26.06.2014
sts_trtu_m          17.07.2014
```

The above doesn't care how many leading or trailing undesirable fields you might have, or what those fields might contain, as long as you don't have 7 leading undesirable fields with the 7th one being a date!

Alternatively, this just prints whatever is first on each side of the string "4 Last update of data":

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+ Last update of data[[:space:]]+' '{
    sub(/.*[[:space:]]/,"",$1)
    sub(/[[:space:]].*$/,"",$2)
    printf "%-20s%10s\n", $1, $2
}' file
namq_aux_lp         07.07.2014
namq_aux_ulc        08.07.2014
namq_aux_gph        07.07.2014
prc_hicp_cann       17.07.2014
namq_nace10_k       02.07.2014
sei_bsco_m          10.06.2014
ei_bsin_m_r2        26.06.2014
lassei_bsbu_m_r2    26.06.2014
assei_bsrt_m_r2     26.06.2014
ei_bssi_m_r2        26.06.2014
ei_bsse_m_r2        26.06.2014
ei_bsci_m_r2        26.06.2014
sts_trtu_m          17.07.2014
```

Comment: Cheers Ed. Very neat.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some that may work:

```
awk '/^10/ {$1=""}1' file | column -t
namq_aux_lp       4  Last  update  of  data  07.07.2014  t
namq_aux_ulc      4  Last  update  of  data  08.07.2014
namq_aux_gph      4  Last  update  of  data  07.07.2014
prc_hicp_cann     4  Last  update  of  data  17.07.2014
namq_nace10_k     4  Last  update  of  data  02.07.2014  clas
sei_bsco_m        4  Last  update  of  data  10.06.2014
ei_bsin_m_r2      4  Last  update  of  data  26.06.2014
lassei_bsbu_m_r2  4  Last  update  of  data  26.06.2014
assei_bsrt_m_r2   4  Last  update  of  data  26.06.2014  t
ei_bssi_m_r2      4  Last  update  of  data  26.06.2014  t
ei_bsse_m_r2      4  Last  update  of  data  26.06.2014
ei_bsci_m_r2      4  Last  update  of  data  26.06.2014
sts_trtu_m        4  Last  update  of  data  17.07.2014  c
```

or to get your output:

```
awk '/^10/ {$1=""}1' file | awk '{print $1,$7}' OFS="\t"
namq_aux_lp     07.07.2014
namq_aux_ulc    08.07.2014
namq_aux_gph    07.07.2014
prc_hicp_cann   17.07.2014
namq_nace10_k   02.07.2014
sei_bsco_m      10.06.2014
ei_bsin_m_r2    26.06.2014
lassei_bsbu_m_r2        26.06.2014
assei_bsrt_m_r2 26.06.2014
ei_bssi_m_r2    26.06.2014
ei_bsse_m_r2    26.06.2014
ei_bsci_m_r2    26.06.2014
sts_trtu_m      17.07.2014
```

Or like this:

```
awk '/^10/ {$1=""}1' file | awk '{print $1,$7}' | column -t
namq_aux_lp       07.07.2014
namq_aux_ulc      08.07.2014
namq_aux_gph      07.07.2014
prc_hicp_cann     17.07.2014
namq_nace10_k     02.07.2014
sei_bsco_m        10.06.2014
ei_bsin_m_r2      26.06.2014
lassei_bsbu_m_r2  26.06.2014
assei_bsrt_m_r2   26.06.2014
ei_bssi_m_r2      26.06.2014
ei_bsse_m_r2      26.06.2014
ei_bsci_m_r2      26.06.2014
sts_trtu_m        17.07.2014
```

Comment: It test if line starts with `10`, remove it.  You could replace it with `/^[[:digit:]]/` if you like to remove first field if it starts with a number.

Comment: @AndyK when you have extra text at the start of the line - is it GUARANTEED to always start with a digit? Similarly, is your desired first field text guaranteed to always NOT start with a digit? Are you guaranteed to never have more than one initial undesirable field?

Comment: Hi Ed, that is the issue. I think most likely it is start with a digit because the 10 is the day. But as I'm doing for this first time, all I can say is that I don't know. 

However , as you can see , most of the first column is populated by files name so even if it has something else, the aim would be to remove the unwanted although I don't know what the unwanted will be.

We can assume that the date will come back every time.

Comment: OK, then you cant use a solution that assumes anything about the contents of the first field.

Comment: Cheers Jotne for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` and `column`:

```
sed -nr 's|.*\b(\S+_\S+)\b.*\b([0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+)\b.*|\1\t\2|p' file | column -t
```

Output:

```
namq_aux_lp       07.07.2014
namq_aux_ulc      08.07.2014
namq_aux_gph      07.07.2014
prc_hicp_cann     17.07.2014
namq_nace10_k     02.07.2014
sei_bsco_m        10.06.2014
ei_bsin_m_r2      26.06.2014
lassei_bsbu_m_r2  26.06.2014
assei_bsrt_m_r2   26.06.2014
ei_bssi_m_r2      26.06.2014
ei_bsse_m_r2      26.06.2014
ei_bsci_m_r2      26.06.2014
sts_trtu_m        17.07.2014
```

Note:

- The column is matched for everything with underscore `_` on it.
- `\S` may not work so you can also consider `[^[:space:]]` or `[^ \t\r]` over it.

Comment: Cheers Konsolebox for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution could be the following:
- removes the first two numbers
- removes spaces
- prints column 1 and 7 with a tab as OFS (Output Field Separator)

```
$ sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]//' telecharge.txt |  sed 's/ //' | awk '{print $1,$7}' OFS='\t'
namq_aux_lp     07.07.2014
namq_aux_ulc    08.07.2014
namq_aux_gph    07.07.2014
prc_hicp_cann   17.07.2014
namq_nace10_k   02.07.2014
sei_bsco_m      10.06.2014
ei_bsin_m_r2    26.06.2014
lassei_bsbu_m_r2        26.06.2014
assei_bsrt_m_r2 26.06.2014
ei_bssi_m_r2    26.06.2014
ei_bsse_m_r2    26.06.2014
ei_bsci_m_r2    26.06.2014
sts_trtu_m      17.07.2014
```

Comment: Cheers Kokkie for your help.